I'm Unable to Upload Videos/audios in Google Gemini API 1.5Pro
Can someone help me to use Google Gemini API1.5Pro model with Video/audio Processing?
I've already searched almost in all search engines, but can't find any resource to learn.
My requirement is to upload an audio file and ask the AI to summarize it.
I'm using Node.js with Google AI Studio(@google/generative-ai)
any suggestion will be highly valued!
I've tried the following:-

I've installed the google generative package and explore with it
the Gemini AI API1.5Pro is working perfectly with text-only results and text-and/or-image results, but I couldn't find any way to explore with audio files and video files.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To add files to gemini 1.5 for processing you must upload the file
To do this we use the media.upload method.
To be clear videos are not supported.  What is supported is images.  What is recommend is that you take 1 frame a second and export it as an image then upload it to the file upload endpoint.  You can then use the files in your request to the AI.
Audio can be uploaded using the same method as uploading the images.
Then we can look at Prompting with media files and here File prompting strategies
To send the actual url to the ai when you run your prompt is doine via the contents
you send the url that was returned when you uploaded the file.
{
  "contents":[
    {
      "parts":[
        {"text": "What is this picture?"},
        {
          "inline_data": {
            "mime_type":"image/jpeg",
            "file_data": {"file_uri": file['uri'], "mime_type": file['mimeType']}}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Its not supported directly in the library yet but you can load it yourself manually.
See:
quickstarts/file-api/sample.js

It's working Properly
After your explanation and examples, I'm able to process Audio Files using Gemini
but what about Videos,
(how to get the frames from a video in nodejs and upload with audio)?
can you give an Example of video upload Process?

I havent tried it yet guess i should but check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/51834464/1841839

Finally I found the sollution:
for images, we can directly insert the base-64 encoded data(without data:image/....;base64,...) and/or we can use the file API
for large files such as audios/videos, its required to use the file API to insure the data(buffer) not crash the application
the file API is a free service that can store upto 20GB of files(each file should not more than 2GB) and lasts for 48hrs from the time of upload
to use the file API, you can check the official gemini documentation
to include a file, you can use {fileData: {fileUri: "", mimeType: ""}}
a specific note about videos:
all video files have a "state" Parameter wich can be "PROCESSING", "FAILED", "ACTIVE". only videos with "state" of "ACTIVE" can be included in the model's requests
